# VB.NET Cryptography(PDF)

Tags: vb.net, pdf, encryption, cryptography

i'm making a system that requires me to **encrypt and decrypt PDF files**

how do i encrypt PDF files and still make it readable(but in a messy way because it was encrypted)
i mean the file can still be opened, not like in other programs that make a custom extension like ***"sample.encrypt"*** where encrypt is the **extension**

the save file should also be ".pdf" and decrypt it back to the original state

*PS: i'm still a student, and i still lack knowledge about this topic but i am open and willing to learn to finish this project*

Comment: If you properly encrypt a file it becomes a random pile of bits and cannot be readable -- period.

Comment: @dbugger so it's not possible to do this in vb.net, 

i have seen other thesis and sites that can encrypt(.txt .word .jpg .png) and decrypt it, it can still be opened, but the text will be in codes or ascii, not the original state.

Comment: No. It's not possible to view an ENCRYPTED file in its original format.  If it is DECRYPTED, of course, then it can be read in its original format.

Answer (score 0):

PDF encryption can have an owner password and a user password. If you set an empty user password, anyone can open it but not be able to make changes to it. If you set a user password, only those who know the password can open it but still be unable to make any changes to it. With the owner password, the file can be opened and changes made to it. By specifying document user permissions, you can restrict features such as high-quality printing, commenting, etc., to for those who know only the user password.

[image]

http://www.gnostice.com/nl_article.asp?id=91&t=Encrypting_and_Decrypting_PDF_Documents_Using_PDFOne_NET

Comment: thanks for the answer, i'll specify this info in our defense that PDF can only be opened but not edited.